# Dependency injection in Azure Functions fails to invoke configuration delegate for a typed HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions, httpclient

I have the following class:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<SomeAzureFunction>(c =>
        {
          // some code
        });
    }
}
}
```

The delegate `c => { // some code }` is never actually invoked? What's going on?

Microsoft [clearly states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#register-services) that they are using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` in this example:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService>((s) => {
            return new MyService();
        });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, MyLoggerProvider>();
    }
}
}
```

The only difference in my usage is that instead of simply registering `IHttpClientFactory`, I'm registering a typed client.

The azure function is with a timer trigger.

The signature of `SomeAzureFunction` is the following:

`public SomeAzureFunction(HttpClient httpClient)`

**EDIT:** It seems that if I change the constructor to instead accept a `IHttpClientFactory` and then do the following with it: `IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(SomeAzureFunction))` it finally decides to execute the delegate, but I don't understand why it wouldn't do that automatically when I inject `HttpClient`.

Comment: What does the Function look like? And some more Context to the snippet would be good. Maybe try and create a [mcve].

Comment: @Fildor Sometimes I don't get it with these requirements for minimal reproducible examples. The whole picture is explained, but they still need water under the bridge. I've added the clarity you requested.

Comment: We still don't know what you are expecting to be injected where. In the second snippet, you set up IHttpClientFactory, yes. But your Service doesn't seem to depend on it and the Function _could_ but we cannot tell.

Comment: @Fildor I'm expecting to inject a typed `HttpClient` in `SomeAzureFunction`, that's all there is to it. It's being injected, but the delegate is not being fired, ever. (this part: `c => { //<some code here> }`). At that point I'm not even sure if it's typed, I might as well remove my code and just use the basic usage of the consumption pattern for `IHttpClientFactory`.

Comment: I'm confused. You don't register any typed clients in your startup. It doesn't contain the first snippet. So, where is it from? And wherever that is - it's probably the wrong place.

Comment: The second snipper is an example provided by microsoft (link included), first snipper is what I've done differently in comparison with the example given by microsoft. I'll edit it to make it more intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what's going on here, we'll need to dive a little deeper. This has nothing to do with Azure Functions, and everything to do with Dependency injection and the way Typed Clients are registered as transient services.

A typed client's type is indeed registered as a transient service in the DI container, but it's being registered with a `Func<IServiceProvider, TService> implementationFactory` [delegate](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs,394). That delegate only gets invoked when the type is passed into a constructor for dependency injection (i.e it's being used for DI).

That means that if we have a type `A`, and we register that type as a typed client via `IServiceCollection.AddHttpClient<A>()`, then if we pass `A` in any of our Azure Functions's constructors, or a Controller (for web applications), it would be resolved as we expected - the `HttpClient` inside `A` would successfully be DI.

But we actually don't wish to pass around `A` in other constructors. We want `A` to simply DI the "typed" `HttpClient`. Then we simply need to register the type `A` in the `IServiceCollection` with the appropriate scope. We do that by calling `IServiceCollection.AddTransient<A>();`.

I said "typed", because in essence, that delegate I mentioned above is really what a "typed" `HttpClient` is all about. In reality - every `HttpClient` registered is a "named" client - `Typed` clients included. They only bring the benefit of registering your named `HttpClient` with your defined type, so you can use dependency injection on that type, rather than doing it the classic way of injecting `IHttpClientFactory` instead, and calling `IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient("namedClient");`

The name of a "typed" `HttpClient` is your type's name. If you did `IServiceCollection.AddHttpClient<HelloWorld>();`, the named client would be called "HelloWorld".

I couldn't understand *why* a service registered via a `Func<IServiceProvider, TService>` delegate behaves in this way, so I'd appreciate if someone brought more detail into that.